# PHP DateTime Format

Tags: php, mysql, date, date-format

How would you change the format of the DATETIME from a MySQL Database.

Code:

```
echo $r["date"];
echo date("F j, g:ia",$r["date"]);
```

Output:

```
2014-02-05 15:31:51
December 31, 6:33pm
```

These are both two different dates, not sure why.

Comment: Look at the documentation for `date` (http://www.php.net/date)... It's second parameter is a unix timestamp, not a string.

Answer (score 3):

`date()` requires the second parameter to be a unix timestamp. You need to pass your datetime string to [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/strtotime) before using it in `date()`

```
echo date("F j, g:ia",strtotime($r["date"]));
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/FJzwfr)

Answer (score 1):

Use strtotime

```
echo date("F j, g:ia",strtotime($r["date"]));
```

The second parameter for the date function requires a timestamp. strtotime converts a date string to a timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
echo date("F j, g:ia",strtotime($r["date"]));
```

Mysql returns a string, not a unix timestamp. You should convert it before using with `date()`.